Help me put this theorem into words
I've come here with yet another elementary theorem which I would like to word properly, but it either turns out lengthy or not using the common notation.
Two lines (not necessarily parallel) are cut by two transversals. These transversals may intersect, but only before or after crossing any of the lines. A pair of alternate interior angles equal to $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is chosen on one transversal, and the analogous pair of alternate interior angles equal to $\gamma$ and $\delta$ is chosen on the other transversal. The theorem states that $\alpha+\delta=\beta+\gamma$.
The proof is the same as given in this question, and it generalizes the theorem in my other question.

I would like to have this theorem in worded form that does not use mathematical symbols, but only relies on common definitions, in fashion similar to this:

If the lines are parallel, then the sum of the co-interior angles is equal to the straight angle.


The sum of the interior angles of a quadrilateral is equal to the circumference of a circle with unit radius.

@Shean I would like it to be formulated in terms of two lines and two transversals.

@Rusurano will this suffice "In a quadrilateral, the sum of two opposite angles is equal to the sum of exterior angles at the remaining two points "

@DS This still uses the 'quadrilateral' instead of formulation in terms of two lines and two transversals; also, this quad should be convex.

What is this for?

@Shean I document interesting theorems, and I want to explain it to someone who haven't yet studied quadrilaterals but who knows about lines and transversals.

But...this isn't true (as stated). For simplicity, imagine you have $\beta=\delta=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Then $\alpha+\gamma=\pi$; but if we take $\alpha<\frac{\pi}{2}$, then $\alpha+\delta<\pi<\beta+\gamma$.

@ChrisLewis How then should it be stated?

@ChrisLewis Oh. So this works only if two transversals do not cross in between two intersected lines. I get it.

@Rusurano the problem is, the theorem you stated is false. So either you just explained it incorrectly, or it isn't actually a theorem. The first thing you should do is check that the theorem works, with some examples (either with GeoGebra or by hand).
